# CPAN - yaml_process_error

Tags: perl, cpan

Hi i've been trying to search for a fix to this but i cant find one.
All im trying to do is update my perl modules using

```
cpan[1]> upgrade
```

How ever i get the following error.

```
Catching error: "CPAN::Exception::yaml_process_error=HASH(0x7fd8f39971f8)" at/Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2/CPAN.pm line 392.
        CPAN::shell() called at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2/App/Cpan.pm line 338
        App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2/App/Cpan.pm line 421
        App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at /usr/bin/cpan5.16 line 12
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What's the output of `o conf yaml_module` in the CPAN shell? Is this YAML module installed and working?

Comment: Can you give us the entire session output as well as the versions of perl, etc?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `o conf yaml_module` to get the yaml config, maybe like this:

```
yaml_module        [YAML::XS]
```

we can use other alternate yaml modules, like `YAML`, `YAML::Sync`. In my case, `YAML` can't process the report file well, so I use `YAML::XS`. You can use `o conf yaml_module MODULE`
to set anyone you like.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

After running the above `o conf` changes, I was able to see that there was a minor bug installing `Debug::Client`.

I changed to the bundle's directory and ran sudo make, followed by sudo make install. No issues. Just wouldn't pass a test.

Now I finally have **Padre** installed.  (Also, my version of Perl shows `Debug::Client` Fails in the **YAML** report, but not why?.)

I changed mine to `YAML::XS` as that works better to parse newer YAML reports.

YMMV, but sometimes it's worth just doing the make, make install steps from the cli, and see if things go smoothly. However, if there's more than one or two errors, I would try to chase down the why's before doing that.