# CPAN-Yaml process error

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

I followed the answers mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207079/cpan-yaml-process-error), but still my problem is not solved.  I tried:

```
o conf yaml_module YAML::XS
```

I then tried changing this to:

```
YAML::Sync YAML YAML::Tiny
```

but no luck. Whenever I tried to install cpan modules the following error comes on the screen:

```
CPAN:Exception YAML_process_error= HASH (0x817abcd)

App::CPAN::process_options
```

One thing more I wanted to mention. If I try installing `YAML` lib by this command:

```
cpan install YAML::LibYAML
```

again no luck. The screen again shows a cpan yaml exception error. Can anyone please help me out here?

Note : I am using windows, `Strawberry` perl version 5.20

Comment: This is clearly a bug; can it be triggered by something weird in your configuration file?

Comment: Can you explain further what should I do with my config.pm file ?  I am very new to this stuff